# Two claims about compositorials

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples, products

This question is inspired by [Fortune's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortunate_number) .

Can you provide proofs or counterexamples for the following two claims :

*First claim*

> If $q$ is the smallest prime greater than $\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n C_i+1$ , where $\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n C_i$ is the product of the first $n$ composite numbers , then $q-\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n C_i$ is prime .

The first few such differences are :

```
3,5,5,5,11,7,23,11,29,17,31...
```

[Try it Yourself !](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx9kMFuwyAMhu99CpZLoGPVOvXUDGlStduOu7VVRKiTIBETgVkjVXv30bTabvMB8WP82f67cQVf2vGi9YESAkehLkatq6yNH0YfLQG3ai1RGmWWVlQBKAXkCBONwQ7AzeOLeDKi-i7E4gQt22lnktN0hW0XLIdtGb5ubvdr3BEf-c_0Po2BF7saD4es6MKGFIk1wLoAOR8Y9RrzEQAecgcxQ8BF-AfXjas2oSHrsTba_a1XyD0exSrqDrjIrDeLuYU2NA9ec1QWx0R14ye-kWWeim1LebYn6tX6WUg9M1UEB4Z84Pvyd9nyKJtE5DGqz5BAOt2AU2Up7h7cSplis983Jdicir0_s_tT9kz8ABDhgnw=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

*Second claim*

> If $q$ is the greatest prime less than $\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n C_i-1$ , where $\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n C_i$ is the product of the first $n$ composite numbers , then $\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n C_i-q$ is prime .

The first few such differences are :

```
2,5,11,5,23,17,13,11,13,23,53...
```

[Try it Yourself !](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx9kMFuwyAMhu99CpZLYGLROvXUDGlStduOu7VVRKiTIlGDwKyVqr37aFJtt_mA_GP4bP9jaOBLO14NPlJG4CjU1ahlW7Txp-CTJeBWLSVKo8yjFW0EyhG5eQoRTIj2BCV_EaL9rsTiAAPbaGey03SDrReshB0Yvq7m_BZ3xEd5c3m_hMirTYe7XVF0ZaeciPXAxgilHhkdNZYjAjyUDmKCgEvwD24MzZDRkPXYGe3-1qvkFveiSXoELgrrzWJpoQ1Ng3cclcWQqev9ha9kXaZi61qe7YGOavkspJ6YKoEDQz7ybf27bL2XfSbymNRnzCCd7sGpuhZ3D-avTLHJ71kJNpXS0Z_Z_ap4Jn4A9amCaQ==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

I have tested both claims up to $n=660$ and there were no counterexamples .

Comment: Very interesting conjectures! Unless, or until, there are counter-examples  within computing range this could  be deep.

Answer (score 2):

here's a list of things we know ( it's a hint or help not an strictly an answer ,partly because I don't know ):

1. q-product for n>1 will have the same modular remainder mod 6 as q.
2. When we take the product up to 2n, we get at least all the primes less than or equal to n up to exponents of 1 or more.
3. all primes less than ${2\over 3}n$ appear at least twice in the product in 2.
4. Generally,all primes less than ${2\over a}n$ will appear at least a-1 times in the product in 2.

   This all means the difference can't divide by any product within the product because then q would not be prime. n# is within this product. so the difference ( again 2n case) has already been trial factored up to n.

Answer (score 1):

For the "first claim" we have...

(perhaps the notation is not correct)

Given

$$1 \le k \le n \textrm{ and } 1 < \ell < q,$$

then

$$q > \prod_{\imath=1}^n C_\imath
\Rightarrow
(q{ \not\mid}C_k) \wedge (C_k{\not\mid}q)
\Rightarrow
\ell{\not\mid}\left(q - \prod_{\imath=1}^n C_\imath\right),$$

whence

$$q - \prod_{\imath=1}^n C_\imath$$

is a prime.

I am working on the "second claim" :)

(corrected the typo... thanks to Peđa Terzić)

Comment: There is a typo in your answer . It should be $C_i$ instead of $C_n$ .

Comment: https://oeis.org/wiki/Compositorial#Formulae